# Mac OS X Remote/Shared Directory full path

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, file-sharing

I have an Ubuntu server and a Mac running Snow Leopard on the same network.

From the Mac, I see the a shared directory "Server Name" that automatically shows up in my Finder with the Screen Sharing. Do you know the full path of that share? I need to access via Terminal/Command line.

Ex: cp my.file //TheSharedDir/...

Basicly, I want to deploy jar from my Mac to the UbuntuServer through that share.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a Finder window of the directory "Server Name" and the drag and drop the icon left to the name of that window on a terminal window.

This gives you the full path.

Answer (score 3):

Check under Volumes. You should see the "root" of your server share there. In your Finder, "go" to /Volumes and you'll see the paths going from there.

Answer (score 2):

One other option since you're using the Terminal is to drag and drop the folder in question into the Terminal window which will fill in the full path for the folder or file you drop onto the Terminal window.